# Since propagation of electricity takes time, does magnetic field (that iron filings organize around) build up gradually from one end toward the other?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, conductors

In very long wires, such as hundreds of kilometers, when we flip a switch and turn on the electricity, does the magnetic field (that iron filings organize around) start to form in one direction and then move through the conductor to the other end? Such that iron filings around the whole wire, would start to react to the magnetic field at different times, with delay the further from the start we get?

If yes, does the magnetic field forming propagate in the opposite direction to conventional current, the direction that the electrons travel in?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHIhgxav9LY

Comment: that video has pretty poor reputation, if you stretch the transmission line with 1 m between ground the wire to a circle, you get (2*300*10^6/pi) m / c = 0.63 s, slightly faster than going through the circumference which takes 1 s.